# How to copy a function from disassembly to Visual Studio and be able to call it from C level?

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly

I'm trying to code a keygen for a "crackme" program. There is a quite long hash function, that would take some time to rewrite it to C, so I'd like just to copy it and place within __asm braces. So my question is what would be the best way to do it?

I was trying do accomplish it this way:

```
void hashFunction(unsigned int * arg1,unsigned int * arg2, unsigned int arg3)
{
    __asm
    {
        // pure copy from disassembly
        PUSHAD
        MOV ESI,DWORD PTR [ESP+0x24] // accesses the first argument
        MOV DWORD PTR [ESI],0x67452301
        MOV DWORD PTR [ESI+0x4],0xEFCDAB89
        ... 
}
```

I was playing with the compiler options, trying to force VS to omit creating a frame stack and disable optimization, but couldn't make it working. 
VS produces this code:

```
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP,ESP
PUSH EBX
PUSH ESI
PUSH EDI
PUSHAD
MOV ESI,DWORD PTR [ESP+24]  // no longer accesses the first argument
MOV DWORD PTR [ESI],67452301
MOV DWORD PTR [ESI+4],EFCDAB89
```

VS creates a frame stack and also pushes some registers onto the stack, which is obviously not desired in this case. I know I could still fix it, but I guess there must be a better way to do it? This is the first time I'm using assembly code in VS, I searched for my problem in google, but I couldn't find any topics related to my question. 
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: So you need help with your malicious plan? :)

Comment: You should be able to just link to an object file compiled from assembly, no? After adding whatever the necessary incantations are to make a symbol table entry for the function in the MS assembler.

Comment: @ddriver Haha, as I said I'm just solving a pre-crafted crackme :)

Comment: @millimoose Some kind of solution as well, I'll keep that in mind, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try the `__declspec(naked)` attribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5w10wxs.aspx):

> For functions declared with the naked attribute, the compiler
>   generates code without prolog and epilog code. You can use this
>   feature to write your own prolog/epilog code sequences using inline
>   assembler code. Naked functions are particularly useful in writing
>   virtual device drivers. Note that the naked attribute is only valid on
>   x86 and ARM, and is not available on x64